# FAQ for the Trinity

Tags: discussion

I'm seeing a lot of questions that are calling into question either the Trinity, or the dual nature of Jesus. The questions are usually couched in slightly different terms, making it hard to close them as duplicates, but the answers always boil down to the same thing. In fact I'm seeing so many of these that I'm wondering if we need a Trinity FAQ that we can refer people to. Is that something we should be doing? Is it possible?

- [Who is the Father or God in Christianity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8701/who-is-father-or-god-in-christianity)

Comment: not sure, honestly sounds like a good blog topic.

Comment: @waxeagle: I was thinking of adding that to our topic list a few days ago...and forgot.  You'll know later today if I drop the ball again. ;-)

Comment: @DJClayworth Personally I find that when OP is insistent on asking the question and refuses to edit even after being pointed that it might be a duplicate, it's usually because they want to make a point. You can judge this from the comments or the tone of the question. In that case I just down vote it.

Comment: and if it really is a dupe, just close as dupe, you've to the rep for it

Comment: @waxeagle I would be nice to have a blog post or two about it, but I would seem strange to close a question because "we have a blog post that addresses that issue." We couldn't answer with that either.

Answer (score 2):

Someone should make a good blog post.

Comment: it's on the list of future topics